# Prove an greater than 11 can be written as a sum of only 3's and only 7's.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, induction

Prove an greater than 11 can be written as a sum of only 3's and only  7's.

Is there a way to do this by strong induction. I would greatly appreciate someone showing me how to apply the classic strong induction technique to this question.

Comment: Hint: You only need to worry about the case when $k=2 \mod 3$. Can you find out why?

Comment: The general problem is called the Frobenius coin problem, the resolution to which is called Sylvester's theorem or the Chicken McNugget theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$12=3+3+3+3,13=3+3+7,14=7+7.$$

Now assume the result to be true for all $n$ such that  $12\le n\le k$, where  $k\ge14$. Then consider $n=k+1$.

$n=3+(k-2)$ where, by assumption $k-2$ can be expressed as an appropriate sum. Hence, by strong induction, every number greater than $12$  can be so expressed.

Comment: Yes - it's fine. It was a clever idea to use the "two or more" method.